# Ways to prevent CSRF and have good cookie etiquette on a no-JavaScript login page?

Tags: http, authentication, cookies, csrf, progressive-enhancement

**Context:** I'm building a website that has a password-locked admin portal. Additionally, JS is only used for *progressive enhancement* of the 100% already-working site.

**Security issue:** The login form is vulnerable to CSRF.

**My fix:** A hidden form token and a pre-session cookie. This is a typical CSRF defense, and works. The pre-session cookie gets set when a user clicks "I Agree" to cookie consent. Remember, this uses no JS, so it happens by means of a POST request.

**Why that was dumb:** The cookie consent page POST request is vulnerable to CSRF.

Yes—it's literally nothing compared to a login CSRF.

But my integrity demands that I fix this. I truly believe that cookie consent should not be forgable.

After two days, I see two solutions:

- Give up and use JavaScript. Just set the pre-session cookie on client side. Good UX and but now JavaScript is a hard requirement.
- <strike>Have a 2nd cookie consent page, which just confirms the first one. Bad UX, but this 2nd page would be immune to CSRF.</strike> **EDIT:** I realized this idea wouldn't work at all, because I would need to have a cookie set to prevent the CSRF to begin with. So, any and all ideas are welcome.

Does anyone have other solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In discussion with a friend, we came up with the following.

Use the Referer header for CSRF protection,  instead of a pre-session cookie. It comes down to checking that the Referer is from the expected domain. If not, the login attempt should fail.

From a UX perspective, this is great. The "Log In" button can now double as the "Accept Cookies" button, so there's only one step.

Some sources say the Referer header is a weaker defense, but it seems like the least troublesome option here.